# Realm AddChangeListner is not Working?

Tags: java, android, realm

I have two classes where one class adds the data in table another class where I have retrieved the data.I have added changeListener but it didn't execute after the table is changed. Below is the code

```
  RealmResults<MessageContentTable> messageContentTables= 
   realmObject.where(MessageContentTable.class).findAllAsync();
    messageContentTables.addChangeListener((collection, changeSet) -> 
     {
        Log.e("Updating 123"+collection.size());

    });
```

Comment: Can you try shifting from async query to a sync query and then try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store field variable (strong reference) to your RealmResults, otherwise it'll be consumed by the garbage collector and Realm won't be able to call the change listener anymore.

```
RealmResults<MessageContentTable> messageContentTables;

public void something() {
    messageContentTables = realm.where(MessageContentTable.class).findAllAsync();
    messageContentTables.addChangeListener((collection, changeSet) -> {
        Log.e("Updating 123"+collection.size());
    });
```